# Users lost after new version is uploaded to Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-glass, google-mirror-api

I am new to Glass development... so hopefully someone has experienced this issue or can tell me what I am doing wrong. I am basically just using the Mirror API sample app downloaded from Google/GitHub. Everything works fine.. I am able to deploy it to our App Engine account and can authenticate via the front end into the app etc etc....

When we make a change to the app and update it on our Google AppEngine instance, are all users who have authenticated lost? It appears that users need to re-authenticate after we make a changes to the code and update it.

I can't seem to figure this out. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please clarify what, exactly, you're doing and which users "are lost"? It isn't clear why this is tagged with both "android" and "mirror-api"

Comment: Sorry, I clicked the recommended tag from Stacks. I have the sample Java Mirror app running. And I have two users authenticated against it. All is fine. Now, if I make a change to the source code and re-upload the new version to App Engine. Those users are lost and they have to re-auth again.

Comment: The user are not lost but their authentication tokens are invalid as the application is new and they need to authorize that new application to have access to their data.

Answer (score 0):

The users will need to reauthenticate since all OAuth tokens are voided when you push a new version. Not to worry, this is expected behaviour.